# What is the most elegant way to standardize a time series by the value in the first period?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with sales by product and year and would like to create a column that divides each product-year by the value of Sales in 2000, separately by product, in order to create "adjusted sales" (`adj_Sales`).

```
library(plyr)
df <- data.frame(Product=gl(3,3,labels=c("A","B", "C")), 
         Year=factor(rep(2000:2002,3)), 
         Sales=1:9)

print(df)
#   Product Year Sales
# 1       A 2000     1
# 2       A 2001     2
# 3       A 2002     3
# 4       B 2000     4
# 5       B 2001     5
# 6       B 2002     6
# 7       C 2000     7
# 8       C 2001     8
# 9       C 2002     9
```

The following code works, but isn't very elegant since it:

- a) creates an intermediate data frame (`base_sales`),
- b) uses a merge with the intermediate data frame (`base_sales`) and the original (`df`),
- c) requires a step to rename of the `Sales` column to `Sales_2000`,
- d) creates an undesired `Sales_2000` column, and

Is there a way to do this all at once using plyr or dplyr?

```
base_sales <- df[df$Year==2000, c("Product","Sales")]
base_sales <- plyr::rename(base_sales, c("Sales" = "Sales_2000"))

print(base_sales)
#   Product Sales_2000
# 1       A          1
# 4       B          4
# 7       C          7

df2 <- merge(df,base_sales,by="Product")
df2$adj_Sales <- df2$Sales / df2$Sales_2000

print(df2)
#   Product Year Sales Sales_2000 adj_Sales
# 1       A 2000     1          1    1.0000
# 2       A 2001     2          1    2.0000
# 3       A 2002     3          1    3.0000
# 4       B 2000     4          4    1.0000
# 5       B 2001     5          4    1.2500
# 6       B 2002     6          4    1.5000
# 7       C 2000     7          7    1.0000
# 8       C 2001     8          7    1.1429
# 9       C 2002     9          7    1.2857
```

Is there a way to do this all at once using plyr or dplyr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can directly create the columns with `mutate` from `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(Product) %>% 
   mutate(Sales_2000= Sales[Year==2000], adj_sales=Sales/Sales_2000)
#   Product Year Sales Sales_2000 adj_sales
#1       A 2000     1          1  1.000000
#2       A 2001     2          1  2.000000
#3       A 2002     3          1  3.000000
#4       B 2000     4          4  1.000000
#5       B 2001     5          4  1.250000
#6       B 2002     6          4  1.500000
#7       C 2000     7          7  1.000000
#8       C 2001     8          7  1.142857
#9       C 2002     9          7  1.285714
```

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, c('Sales_2000', 'adj_sales') := {tmp=Sales[Year==2000]
               list(tmp, Sales/tmp)}, by =  Product]
#   Product Year Sales Sales_2000 adj_sales
#1:       A 2000     1          1  1.000000
#2:       A 2001     2          1  2.000000
#3:       A 2002     3          1  3.000000
#4:       B 2000     4          4  1.000000
#5:       B 2001     5          4  1.250000
#6:       B 2002     6          4  1.500000
#7:       C 2000     7          7  1.000000
#8:       C 2001     8          7  1.142857
#9:       C 2002     9          7  1.285714
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun ! I'm just starting w/ dplyr. It's beautiful! ... Ah, I see, the "Sales[Year==2000]" gets recycled across the entire group.

Comment: @dchandler Perhaps `df %>% group_by(Product) %>% mutate(SumSales= sum(Sales), SalesNew=Sales/SumSales)`